# How Change profile for Websphere portal server

Tags: websphere, portal, websphere-portal

How did this profile get created? Also is there a way to change it? When I run profile management tool to create a new profile, that profile is created for WAS and not WPS. So that is not available for selection in the WPS settings page.

Answer (score 0):

When you run PMR tool , do you see a new template one for WPS ? If there is not one for WPS , then you do not have WPS installed . 
VT, opinions are my own and not those of my employer